# Angular 12 TypeError: Cannot read property 'bootstrap' of null

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am updating an Angular 10 application to Angular 12 and I receive the following error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'bootstrap' of null**

Here are my Angular files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json configurations

```
            "production": {
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": false,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
             "buildOptimizer": false,
             "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": false,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
             "outputHashing": "all",
           }
          }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-angular",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && ng serve -o"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "3.10.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "12.1.1",
    "ajv": "6.12.5",
    "arrive": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "chartist": "0.11.4",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "81.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.0",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.3",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.1.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.5.0",
    "@types/chartist": "0.11.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.14",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.6",
    "@types/node": "14.11.5",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "6.0.0",
    "karma": "5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "9.0.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I tried changing the versions of the packages and also different options for the angular.json configurations but nothing works. Any idea will be really helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related ticket: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19866

Comment: Hi @MichaelD, the solution provided there doesn't fit my case..

Answer (score 1):

change

```
"aot": true,
"buildOptimizer": false,
"optimization": false,
```

in angular.json configurations like above